# Need to understand printf functioning deeply

Tags: c, printf

I tried the below mentioned code and to my surprise getting somewhat relevant output.

```
void main( )
  { char s[]="USMComputer";
     printf("%*.*s",-5, 4, s+3);
  }
```

This outputs *Comp*. Can someone explain this?

Comment: Did you google for anything?

Comment: It takes `4` characters from `s+3`, that meas starting from C of USMComputer string

Comment: printf is such an old function, I'm sure any half-decent programming site will have an article on it. -1 for not doing any searching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would make sense if you knew a li'l bit about awk. Anyways what happens here is that the * is replaced by the numbers you've given (-5 and 4 respectively), which means

> printf("%*.*s",-5, 4, s+3);

would change to

> printf("%-5.4s", s+3);